# Optional Unix tools for Windows Git Installation

Tags: git, unix, cmd, git-bash

I have a question and have researched without much success about this.

Can someone explain, in practice the optional Unix Tools that the option from Git installation grants for Windows users? Will it allow me to use the same Unix commands as Mac OS users?

I do use cmd prompt from Windows, but I work with a team of Mac users, so will this optional tooling make our commands match? I am getting errors when trying to do things because Windows cmd works differently from Mac OS, which is based on Unix, as I researched. I am trying commands such as yarn dev command (to run a script to set the project) like Mac users do and it is failing, and people told me is because of variables that need to be set. The script does them for Mac, but it fails because variables are set differently for Windows apparently.

[image: Git Installation with optional Unix Tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using unix tools won't solve your problems. I don't think that 'yarn' is using unix tools. The few I use yarn, I remember it was working in a cmd.

But git provide also a 'bash' which much more similar to Mac shell. So perhaps you will have some luck using it. It at least increase your chances of success of using it.

But without a real example of the errors that occurred, we could not give you a perfect answer...

Ps : but adding the unix tool to the PATH is still a good idea. That way you could use cmd or bash alternatively.